# How to add ngClass to span with ngFor based on localStorage value

Tags: javascript, jquery, angular

Trying to add `active-span` to an element when selecting a `size`, its quite simple doing it in jQuery but I'm a bit confused when doing it in Angular. So when select a size `S/M/L` it will add a new class called `active-span` as well as when the page is refreshed since the `sizeVal` is saved in `localStorage()`.

I tried using `ngClass` but it's not adding the class to the `div` element.

```
size: any;
sizeOpt:any;
private sizeOptionStorage = localStorage.getItem('sizeOpt');

  constructor() {
    this.size = ['XS', 'S', 'M', 'L', 'XL'];
  }

selectSize(event) {
    this.sizeOpt = event.target.innerText;
    localStorage.setItem('sizeOpt', this.sizeOpt);
    console.log(this.sizeOpt);
    // add class when size is selected
  }
```

template html --

```
<div *ngFor="let s of size" class="size" [ngClass]="{'active-span': sizeOptionStorage}" (click)="selectSize($event)">
    <span> {{ s }} </span>
  </div>
```

Here's a plnkr to replicate what I'm trying to do.

[Sample Plnkr](https://plnkr.co/edit/jT1NGG3BVSp9YXb2wGZH?p=preview)

In jQuery it'd be something like this

```
$('.size').on('click', function () {
    spanText = $(this).text();
    localStorage.setItem('sizeOption', spanText);
    spanText = $(this).text();
    $('div.size').each(function () {
        $(this).removeClass('active-span');
    });
    $(this).addClass('active-span');
})

$('div.size').each(function () {
    if ($(this).html() == sizeOption) {
        $(this).addClass('active-span');
    }
});
```

Comment: If you update the code in your question to fix typos, it would be nice if you would mention that somewhere.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You can store current value in variable:

```
value: any;

selectSize(event) {
    this.sizeOpt = event.target.innerText;
    localStorage.setItem('sizeOpt', this.sizeOpt);
    this.value = localStorage.getItem('sizeOpt');
    console.log(this.sizeOpt);
}
```

And then you can take advantage of `NgClass` directive like this:

```
<div *ngFor="let s of size" class="size" [ngClass]="{'active-span': s == value}" (click)="selectSize($event)">
    <span>
        {{ s }}
    </span>
</div>
```

Of course, you need to remove code which is breaking your app at the moment:

```
if(sizeOptionSotrage == this.sizeOpt) {
  // show active size from localStorage
}
```

Comment: ah cool thanks, thought making a `private` var would do the trick. yeah about the `if()` forgot to comment it out earlier when paste the URL.

Comment: @MrNew Edited my answer, it's better to do it with variable than with function.

Comment: but the active state doesn't stay when refreshed, have to put `this.value = localStorage..` in the `constructor{}`.

Comment: @MrNew Absolutely, put that in both `constructor()` and `selectSize()`.

Comment: Why did you change your answer from using a `function()` to `variable` instead?

Comment: @MrNew Because it's bad practise to use function like that in template, it's called on every change detection cycle, recommended practise is to always use variables in situations like this.

Answer (score 0):

1. `sizeOptionSotrage` !== `sizeOptionStorage`

You got the variable wrong in your `constructor` because of a typo.

2. You might need to change that to `this.sizeOptionStorage`